# Plot Projects - java.lang.RuntimeException - Already Processing Events

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I am having this error within the Plot Projects on Android devices. Current SDK version I am using for Android Studio is 23, and the version of Plot we are using is 1.10.0.

I wanted to just check if it may be something to do with not checking if Plot has already been initialized or if it's something a little deeper of concern.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Already processing events
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.e.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.e.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.c.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.c.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.c$1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.n.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.n.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.c.c$2.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.a.a.a$1.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.plotprojects.retail.android.internal.a.a.c$a$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add the code whenever the exception occurs?

Comment: 1.10.0 is a version that is over a year old. I would recommend trying a more recent version to see if the problem then still persists.